# store image path in mysql table

Tags: mysql

Please, how to store image path in mysql table ? 
I have tried this, is it correct ?

```
create table image_table
(
    ID     INTEGER  not null,
    path   varchar(256),
    primary key (ID)
)
```

Comment: Try it, does it work?

Comment: it's works in Mysql, but the problem is , how can i  load the image from the path using  language r using  varchar type?

Comment: I don't understand? Just perform a connection to the database and SELECT it?

Comment: I have performed the connection to the database successfully, but more specifically, I want to read this image from its path which is stored in the table in order to extract the pixel values.

Comment: The just SELECT the column?

Comment: in R langage, how to select it? do you have idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `INTEGER`  to `INT`

try that :

```
 create table image_table
(
ID     INT not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
path   varchar(256),
primary key (ID)
)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i don't know if i can load the image from the path which is varchar type knowing that i use r?

Comment: @user3793982 why can't you load it? which language you are using? Its possible in java and php, most probably in all others also.

Comment: image will be loaded to its folder , and you just store path name in your database , if you dont load its php question or your language not database. here you just store path name.

Comment: how can i store the path name in Mysql ?